# How to apply a CSS override to block relative date

Tags: css

In this source code I would like to use an override to prevent the "lightning-relative-date-time" item from being used. I want it to stick with the default of using the timestamp info. How to do this with a CSS override?

```
<feeds_timestamping-comment-creation class="cuf-commentAge slds-text-body_small slds-p-top_xxx-small" title="Apr 4 2019, 03:50 PM" data-data-rendering-service-uid="565" data-aura-rendered-by="127:733;a"><time datetime="2019-04-04T13:50:32.000Z"><lightning-relative-date-time>a month ago</lightning-relative-date-time></time></feeds_timestamping-comment-creation>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: is it pure css? can you please add more relevant code, so that its easy to understand, that what is you problem.

Comment: No I don't think it's "pure" CSS, I am using F12 in Chrome to just pull the code from the HTML rendered page. Again it is Salesforce platform so I cannot alter the source, only use overrides, etc. to force changes. To view the source, for example look at this page: https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000AAHj7ASQT/2019-stm32-wish-list . Note in the Replies, under author's name, is a relative date (like "4 months ago"). If you inspect the object, it shows what I included above. So it seems to me it is calling the absolute date/timestamp, but instead is replacing it with a relative date.

Comment: I want to force it to ignore the relative date and just use the absolute date/time.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is a trick question but:

```
 lightning-relative-date-time {
 display:none;
 }
```

and do you have code that's dynamically pulling in the actual current time?

Comment: Is not a trick question! I tried your suggestion, but I don't want to eliminate the display of the date/time, just don't want it to use the relative option, but rather force it to use the absolute date/timestamp that the code is initially calling up (I think).